# mypy: Missing positional argument

Tags: python, mypy, typing, linter

I am using mypy as linter and a bit confused how default arguments are treated.
I use following type annotation:

```py
def func(dict_1: Dict[str, Any], dict_2: Optional[Dict[str, str]])
```

and real function is signature is:

```py
def func(dict_1, dict_2=None)
```

in [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#optional-types-and-the-none-type) I see that if my argument default value is None, then I am allowed to use `Optional` (see 3rd note at the end of the chapter)
but I get following error:

```
error: Missing positional argument "dict_2" in call to "func"  [call-arg]
```

am I allowed by linter to call functions like this `func(dict_val)` and leave default argument unfilled ?

Comment: An argument with a default (so optional from the perspective of the caller) is different than an argument with type `Optional`. `dict_2: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None` should make `mypy`'s check pass.

Comment: as you see, I am using that, I just have typing in stub file. and that does not work

Comment: You are using `dict_2: Optional[Dict[str, str]]` without the ` = None` that comes after it (or ` = ...` if in a stub file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the type hints in a stub file, which means you should write the below to indicate to `mypy` that `dict_2` has a default argument:

```
dict_2: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = ...
```